# VBA Find Amount Differences Between Books and Sub-Books

Tags: excel, vba, dataset

I have two large data sets of 70,000+ records which may be more or less depending on the day. Sheet 1 has the information pulled from today and Sheet 2 has the information from yesterday. These are accounting series.

Column E has the region. Column G has several (many) different Book Id's. Those books may have a sub-book in column K. Now column N, has an amount established for each book and sub-book. What I need to do is build a Macro to generate a report that finds the difference between day 1 and day 2 for each book and its sub-book.

Now the tricky part here is that the sub-book in Column K may be used several times in different books from Column G.

What I did was Concatenate all the information in one sheet, build a pivot table and get those differences. But when I try to build the report using a Vlookup and creating a unique identifier I find a dead end since many sub-books are used in different books and regions.

I'm attaching a brief example to show how the data interrelates.

Sheet 1

[image: Sheet1]

Sheer2

[image: Sheet2]

As you can see Row 2 is in City QN. The Book ID is FLC and Sub-Book TTL555 with 53,000.00. I need to compare this position with the one in sheet 2 (if any) and get the amount difference. Now the thing is that sub-book TTL555 is also used in Row 11 in a different city and under a different book too.

Any ideas?

This is the Code I'm using for the pivot (I don't really need a pivot is just I couldn't figure out another way to do it)

```
'Create Pivot Table

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Differences"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("Differences")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Concatenated")

'Define Data Range
Lastrow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(Lastrow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="Differences")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="StatusReport")
          
'Insert Data Field
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SD Differences").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
"Differences").PivotFields("Qty"), "Sum of Qty", xlSum

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Differences").PivotFields("Book ID")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Differences").PivotFields("Security Code")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

 'Insert Column Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Differences").PivotFields("Position Date")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
   
End With
    
 'Add a calculated field to compute variance
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Differences").PivotFields("Sum of Qty")
.Calculation = xlDifferenceFrom
.BaseField = "Position Date"
.BaseItem = "(Previous)"
.NumberFormat = "0.00"
.Name = "Position Difference"
End With
    
'Remove Grand Total
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Differences").PivotSelect "'Row Grand Total'", _
    xlDataAndLabel, True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Differences").RowGrand = False

Dim src As Range
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set src = Range("B2").CurrentRegion
Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
ws2.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=src, xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium1").Name = "Differences"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What combination should be compared between sheets?  CITY+BOOK+SUB_BOOK, or is BOOK+SUB_BOOK unique?  Will each unique combination from sheet 1 be found somewhere on sheet2 (and vice-versa) ?   What kind of output are you expecting to generate?  Seems like a pivot table with city, book and sub-book as row fields and date as the column field would do what you need.